# jQuery - Side panel jumping on page load using cookie

Tags: jquery

I have a script I have been working on for a slide in/out panel, as a final piece I have incorporated jQuery Cookie which i'm not sure I have done correctly but it works fine when I test it locally however when I reload/refresh the page the panel loads expanded and then quickly shuts, how can I get the cookie to just keep it shut on page load. 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/sgxu69es/4/)

```
$(function () {
if ($.cookie('myCookieName')) {
    $('#slideClick').click();
}
});

$('#slideClick').click(function () {
var it = $(this).data('it') || 1;
switch (it) {
    case 1:
        $(this).parent().animate({ right: '-345px' }, { queue: false, duration: 500 });
        $(".slideClose").addClass('hideBtn');
        $(".slideOpen").removeClass('hideBtn');
        break;
    case 2:
        $(this).parent().animate({ right: '-0px' }, { queue: false, duration: 500 });
        $(".slideOpen").addClass('hideBtn');
        $(".slideClose").removeClass('hideBtn');
        break;
}
it++;
if (it > 2) it = 1;
$(this).data('it', it);
$.cookie('myCookieName', '1')
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnLoad, you have to initially set the position of your div so as it will be hidden. Then in the onClick event, you have to reverse your switch case and it should work. See **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgxu69es/19/)**.

```
  $(function() {
        $('#slideOut').css('right','-345px');        
        if ($.cookie('myCookieName')) {
          $('#slideClick').click();
        }
  });

  $('#slideClick').click(function() {
      var it = $(this).data('it') || 1;
      switch (it) {
        case 2:
          $(this).parent().animate({
            right: '-345px'
          }, {
            queue: false,
           duration: 500
          });
          $(".slideClose").addClass('hideBtn');
          $(".slideOpen").removeClass('hideBtn');
          break;
        case 1:
          $(this).parent().animate({
            right: '0px'
          }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
          });
          $(".slideOpen").addClass('hideBtn');
          $(".slideClose").removeClass('hideBtn');
          break;
      }
      it++;
      if (it > 2) it = 1;
      $(this).data('it', it);
      $.cookie('myCookieName', '1')
  });
```

Note: Remove the **-** on `-0px`.

Answer (score 0):

By calling $('#slideClick').click(), you're telling it to animate, which takes 0.5 seconds.  Instead, you may want to immediately hide the panel by doing something like this:

```
$(function () {
    if ($.cookie('myCookieName')) {
        $('#slideOut').css('right','-345px');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, unfortunately I have run into one more issue, if you reload the page/frame you have to click on the tab twice to open it back up, any ideas. I have updated my Fiddle

Comment: You probably need to set the it variable to the closed value there as well.

Comment: You just have to change you reverse your switch case https://jsfiddle.net/sgxu69es/11/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a flash of unstyled content, consider adding the property `right: -345px;` to the CSS selector `#slideOut`. That way people don't see it for a split second before jQuery loads and the `click()` method is called.